# can i add two dedicated graphics card in my dell inspiron 5420 laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have got a 1GB dedicated graphics card geforce gt 630M in my dell inspiron 5420 laptop. Can i add another 2 or 4GB graphics card to my laptop as my autocad and and lumion can hardly run in my present 1 GB graphics card?

specs: intel core i7 3632QM @2.2ghz  2.2ghz

ram: 8gb (7.86 gb usable)

os: windows 8.1 64 bit

graphics card: geforce gt 630M
dedicated graphics memory: 1 gb
total graphics memory: 4Gb
shared system memory: 3gb

Comment: No;  You can't upgrade it either considering your current one is soldered to the board.

Comment: @binayashahi - [Here](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/752420/asus-k55vm-geforce-gt-630m-upgrade/) is some additional information that you might useful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know no laptop allows to change the gpu because most (or all) are soldered to the board - as said by Ramhound in the comments.

However you could use an external GPU together with your laptop as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bP_8EYQ-2RA

But in that case it might be more practicable to upgrade to a new laptop.

Comment: Many laptops do allow you to change the GPU but those tend to be gaming-orientated laptops designed specifically for the purpose. There is a standard (MXM) for swappable laptop graphics modules.